# filepicker library not working in fragment

Tags: android

i am trying to select multiple photo from gallery using filepicker library. photo can be selected but after that onactivityresult not calling.

```
imageUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    final AlertDialog.Builder imageIntent = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    imageIntent.setTitle("Please select a source");
                    imageIntent.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                            } else {

                                FilePickerBuilder.getInstance().setMaxCount(5)
//                                        .setSelectedFiles(imageListForServer)
                                        .enableImagePicker(true)
                                        .setActivityTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                                        .pickPhoto(getActivity());
                                startActivityForResult(null,FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    imageIntent.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                            } else {
                                Intent captureImageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                if (captureImageIntent.resolveActivity(context_newsfeed.getPackageManager()) != null)
                                    startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    imageIntent.create().show();
                }
            });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    imageListForServer = data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerConst.KEY_SELECTED_MEDIA);

}
}
```

filepicker version:

```
compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.1.1'
```

what is the issue i could not find.please can anybody solve this issue.or how can i select multiple photo from gallery android, any suggestion

Comment: Do your activity and fragment is having onActivityResult??

Comment: yes,.,.,.,.,....

Comment: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); is there in the onActivityResult of Activity?

Comment: yes already there exist that

Comment: Please provide both onActivityResult of fragment and Activity

Comment: onactivityresult is calling for other function like location check action of map. maybe be problem is other

Comment: i edited the ques please check

Comment: startActivityForResult(getActivity(),FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO); i think this will fix your issue